# Split an image of multiple digits into seperate images having one digit only

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am trying to split an image of hand written digits into separate ones.

Consider I have this image:

[image: Image to split]

I did a simple logic that could work, but it will and it did encounter a problem:

```
private static void SplitImages()
{
    //We're going to use this code once.. to split our own images into seperate images.. can we do this somehow?
    Bitmap testSplitImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("TestSplitImage.jpg");
    int[][] imagePixels = new int[testSplitImage.Width][];
    for(int i=0;i<imagePixels.Length;i++)
    {
        imagePixels[i] = new int[testSplitImage.Height];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<imagePixels.Length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<imagePixels[i].Length;j++)
        {
            Color c = testSplitImage.GetPixel(i, j);
            imagePixels[i][j] = (c.R + c.G + c.B) / 3;
        }
    }

    //let's start by getting the first height vector... and count how many of them is white..dunno..
    int startColNumber = 0;
    int endColNumber = 0;
    bool isStart = false;
    int imageNumber = 1;

    for(int i=0;i<imagePixels.Length;i++)
    {
        int whiteNumbers = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<imagePixels[i].Length;j++)
        {
            if (imagePixels[i][j] > 200)
            {
                //consider it white or not really relevant
                whiteNumbers++;
            }
        }
        if (whiteNumbers > testSplitImage.Height*95.0/100.0)
        {
            //let's consider that if a height vector has more than 95% white pixels.. it means that we can start checking for an image
            //now if we started checking for the image.. we need to stop
            if (isStart)
            {
                //consider the end of image.. so the end column should be here or we make it +1 at least
                endColNumber = i + 1;
                isStart = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isStart)
            {
                isStart = true; //we will start checking for the image one row before that maybe?
                startColNumber = i == 0 ? i : i - 1;
            }
        }
        if (endColNumber > 0)
        {
            //we got a start and an end.. let's create a new image out of those pixels..hopefully this will work
            Bitmap splittedImage = new Bitmap(endColNumber - startColNumber + 1, testSplitImage.Height);
            int col = 0;
            for(int k=startColNumber;k<=endColNumber;k++)
            {
                for (int l=0;l<testSplitImage.Height;l++)
                {
                    int c = imagePixels[k][l];
                    splittedImage.SetPixel(col, l, Color.FromArgb(c, c, c));
                }
                col++;
            }
            splittedImage.Save($"Image{imageNumber++}.jpg");
            endColNumber = 0;
        }
        whiteNumbers = 0;
    }
}
```

I did get good results:

[image: 2] [image: 1] [image: 9]

I did also get the three zeros:

[image: 0-1] [image: 0-2] [image: 0-3]

However, I got this as one image also:

[image: 37]

This is one sample of an image that needs to be split (out of 4,000 images mainly), and it's one of the best and easiest one. I am wondering if there's a way to improve my logic, or I should drop this way and find another?

Comment: The reason this happens is that 3 and 7 both have a black point in the same column, I have worked on this before, but as I don't have time to write code right now, I just want to give the idea, after you found a black point, you should check its neighbors and add all that are black and then check the neighbors of the added points and so on till you don't find any black neighbors. and if you load the image in an array (search for **lockbits**) it will be a thousand time faster than processing pixel by pixel. by the end of the day I will try to add an answer.

Comment: Thank you @AshkanMobayenKhiabani for the information. I'll look into that and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code only works with monochrome (2 color, black and white) images.

```
 public static class Processor
    {
        public static byte[] ToArray(this Bitmap bmp) // bitmap to byte array using lockbits
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr ptr = data.Scan0;
            int numBytes = data.Stride * bmp.Height;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, numBytes);
            bmp.UnlockBits(data);
            return bytes;
        }


        public static int GetPixel(this byte[] array, int bpr, int x, int y) //find out if the given pixel is 0 or 1
        {
            int num = y * bpr + x / 8;
            return (array[num] >> 7- x%8) & 1;
        }

        public static List<Point> getDrawingPoints(this Point start, byte[] array, int width, int height) // get one 0 point (black point) and find all adjacent black points by traveling neighbors  
        {
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
            points.Add(start);
            int BytePerRow = array.Length / bmp.Height;
            int counter = 0;
            do
            {
                for (int i = Math.Max(0, points[counter].X - 1); i <= Math.Min(width - 1, points[counter].X + 1); i++)
                    for (int j = Math.Max(0, points[counter].Y - 1); j <= Math.Min(height - 1, points[counter].Y + 1); j++)
                        if (array.GetPixel(BytePerRow, i, j) == 0 && !points.Any(p => p.X == i && p.Y == j))
                            points.Add(new Point(i, j));
                counter++;
            } while (counter < points.Count);
            return points;
        }
        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this List<Point> points) // convert points to bitmap
        {

            int startX = points.OrderBy(p => p.X).First().X,
                endX = points.OrderByDescending(p => p.X).First().X,
                startY = points.OrderBy(p => p.Y).First().Y,
                endY = points.OrderByDescending(p => p.Y).First().Y;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(endX - startX + 1, endY - startY + 1);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Rectangle(0, 0, endX - startX - 1, endY - startY - 1));
            for (int i = startY; i <= endY; i++)
                for (int j = startX; j <= endX; j++)
                    if (points.Any(p => p.X == j && p.Y == i)) bmp.SetPixel(j - startX, i - startY, Color.Black); 
            return bmp;
        }
    }
```

And use it like this to get all numbers inside the main image:

```
 List<Point> processed = new List<Point>();
 Bitmap bmp = ((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(SourceBitmapPath));
 byte[] array = bmp.ToArray();
 int BytePerRow = array.Length / bmp.Height;
 int imgIndex = 1;
 for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
     {
          if (array.GetPixel(BytePerRow, i, j) == 0 && !processed.Any(p => p.X == i && p.Y == j))
          {
               List<Point> points = new Point(i, j).getDrawingPoints(array, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
               processed.AddRange(points);
               Bitmap result = points.ToBitmap();
               result.Save($"{imgIndex++}.bmp");
           }

      }
```

I'm using paint and Save As monochrome bmp format to generate the source image.

I also tested it with this Image:
[image]

that result in the following three images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will test it against the images I currently have and get back to you. All the images are already black&white here (hopefully I am not mistaken).

Comment: I got some really weird results. I can't really explain what I got. I did try to save it as monochrome bmp image from paint and got ever weirder stuff. I will take a look at your code maybe I can find what's causing the problem.

Comment: it actually worked with my own test file fine, but yeah tried with yours and got weird result, let me just check it and get back to you. sorry.

Comment: this line is repeated 2 times in code: ` int BytePerRow = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)width / 8);` once in Process.cs and once in main code. please change both to:`int BytePerRow = array.Length / Bmp.Height;` and `int BytePerRow = array.Length / height;`. this is because sometimes lockbits adds some empty extra bytes to the byte array taht causes miscalculation of BytesPerRow. just change the way it is calculated. I also added an image that I tested the code with, this is to show that no matter x or y of the letters may be the same but this can still separate them.

Comment: @PaulKaram and if you test the image i sent please first change it to monochrome. the image was not supported to upload here so i converted it to png.

Comment: I did test it with my image and got good results. Thank you again for your time. I'll run it through my 4K images.. after converting them to monochrome bitmap image..somehow.